# Does number of fetched columns have impact on MySQL query speed?

Tags: mysql

Say I have a Table with multiple columns. Is there a speed difference between selecting all columns, or just a subset of the columns, like below?

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE colX = "value"
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM Table WHERE colX = "value"
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't select all columns unless you need all of them. Instead you should select just the needed ones by simply inputing  tablename.columname for every column needed.

Comment: There is no explanation in this answer. Please add more detail and address the 'speed difference' the question is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

From a raw table, the actual query itself will take the same amount of time.  However, returning the results will vary.  And, for such a simple query, this might dominate the time.

If the table contains very large columns, then records would span multiple pages ("overflow" pages), then there might be a performance difference.  I do not think all the overflow pages are read into memory at once.  So, explicitly referencing only a subset of columns that does *not* include the large columns might be faster.  How this is handled in MySQL might also depend on the file system being used.

However, if the "table" is really a view, then it could have a big impact.  Also, some databases support computed/calculated columns.  If these were present, then that could have an effect on performance.

Also, some databases are "column" oriented, where the columns are actually stored separately.  In such a database, there could be a a big difference in performance between these versions of the query.